# Concatenate in DAX PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

For a recent project I have to make a PowerBI Dashbord. I've got the theory down and know precisely which KPI's I want and how to get them but it seems like I have a syntax issue, which is normal since I'm completely new to DAX.

**context**

*I have columns containing a last name and a first name. I want to merge them into 1 column. After that I'm going to compare the records of this new table to an already existing table. To finish it off I'll divide the amount of matches with the total amount*

So for each step I'll be using a measure. Are there better ways to accomplish this?

First measure: Concatenate = ('column1'[firstname] ; 'column2'[lastname]) => *row x A single value cannot be determined for this column* this already failed and I don't have a clue of why it failed. Could anyone help me fix it?

I can figure out the rest of the things that I need to do for the project if I get the syntax of DAX down and/or know what went wrong with my basic measure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a measure, this is cleaner to do with a calculated column:

```
Concatenated Column = TableName[firstname] & " " & TableName[lastname]
```

For a measure, it's similar but you need to use aggregating functions:

```
Concatenated Measure = MAX(TableName[firstname]) & " " & MAX(TableName[lastname])
```

Comment: Hey, that's a good suggestion but the thing is that I'm working with a live connection so I can't make a concatenated column. Any workarounds?

Comment: See my edit. That should work unless you have some odd filter context in your visual.